# Java ActionListener not performing first action before function calls

Tags: java, actionlistener

I've created an actionlistener connected to a button. On press it is suppose to change a label's text
then perform a function call. The function call is intensive enough that the program may seem to freeze up so the label just says "calculating please wait." However on button click the label is never displayed before the function call and lag hits. I have tried various ways of displaying the label as well as trying to add a sleep function to increase the time before function call. Any ideas?

```
lineup.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            calculating.setText("Calculating Lineup! please be patient."); //The text to be displayed"

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#.00");
                lineupSet lineup = genetic.runGenetic(parser); //Function call causing hangup


                QB.setText("QB: " + lineup.lineUp.get(0).getPlayerName()); //Text displayed after function
```

Comment: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) would be a recommended place to start

Comment: That does indeed send me in the right direction, thank you! If possible though, i dont understand why its not performing the .setText line first though. From my understanding the .setText is pausing then the .runGenetic is finished getting called first?

Comment: Swing is single threaded.  The `actionPerformed` method is called on the "event dispatching thread", which is responsible for managing all the events, including painting.  So, while your `actionPerformed` method is blocking the EDT, nothing can be repainted (repaints aren't immediate)

Answer (score 0):

You should start by having a looking at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

From the sounds of your problem, you want to make use of a `SwingWorker`, for (a rough) example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class SoTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SoTest();
    }

    public SoTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {

            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 92, 8, 92));

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Make it so");
            JButton button = new JButton("Push me");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(label, gbc);
            add(button, gbc);

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label.setText("Rummaging through your stuff");
                    button.setEnabled(false);

                    SwingWorker<String, String> worker = new SwingWorker<String, String>() {
                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
                            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                                publish(Integer.toString(index));
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            }
                            return "";
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                            // Important, you will want to check chunks, as the
                            // API will consolidate calls to this if publish
                            // is fast enough
                            label.setText(label.getText() + ".");
                        }

                    };
                    worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                            if (worker.getState() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                                button.setEnabled(true);
                                label.setText("Make it so");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    worker.execute();
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```